# ¿Alguien me puede explicar las igualdades de instancias de objetos?

Tags: java, lista, poo, pilas

Tengo este problema, es un ejercicio de interfaz gráfica con listas tipo pila, pero me está costando entender el código porque en este se igualan las instancias de los objetos, necesito conocer cuál es la función de igualar las instancias o si hay algun metodo más puntual para hacer este código. Muchas gracias, de antemano. A continuación la clase con los métodos y la clase con los atributos necesarios para crear una pila:

PD: La clase principal sólo mantiene el menú de opcciones con un *switch-case* para poder elegir la funcion que se necesita que haga el programa, por eso no lo agregué.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Pila {

      private Nodo ultimoValorIngresado;
      private int tamano;
      private String Lista = "";

      //Constructor
      public Pila(){
          ultimoValorIngresado = null;
          tamano = 0;
      }

      //Metodo para saber si la pila esta vacía
      public boolean PilaVacia(){
          return ultimoValorIngresado == null;
      }

      //Metodo para insertar un nodo en la pila
      public void InsertarNodo(int nodo){
          Nodo nuevoNodo = new Nodo(nodo);
          nuevoNodo.siguiente = ultimoValorIngresado;
          ultimoValorIngresado = nuevoNodo;
          tamano++;
        }

      //Metodo para eliminar un nodo en la pila
      public int EliminarNodo(){
          int auxiliar = ultimoValorIngresado.informacion;
          ultimoValorIngresado = ultimoValorIngresado.siguiente;
          tamano--;
          return auxiliar;
      }

      //Metodo para conocer cual es el ultimo valor ingresado
      public int MostrarUltimoValorIngresado(){
          return ultimoValorIngresado.informacion;
      }

      //Metodo para conocer el tamaño de la pila
      public int TamanoPila(){
          return tamano;
      }

      //Metodo para vaciar la pila
      public void VaciarPila(){
          while (!PilaVacia()){
              EliminarNodo();
          }
      }

      //Metodo para mostrar el contenido de la pila
      public void mostrarContenido(){
          Nodo recorrido = ultimoValorIngresado;

          while(recorrido != null){
              Lista += recorrido.informacion + "\n";
              recorrido = recorrido.siguiente;
          }
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Lista);
          Lista = "";
        }
    }
```

```
public class Nodo {
    
    // "informacion" = contenido del nodo, "siguiente" = penultimo nodo agregado a la pila
    int informacion;
    Nodo siguiente;
    
   // Constructor
    public Nodo(int valor){
        informacion = valor;
        siguiente = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es porque se hace  nuevoNodo.siguiente = ultimoValorIngresado; y ultimoValorIngresado = nuevoNodo; ???

Comment: Exactamente colega ¿Podrías ayudarme?

Comment: 1) En programación cuando uno habla de igualdad, generalmente habla del ==, es decir cuando 2 elementos son iguales. El operador = es una asignación, a=b lo "lo que está en b, ahora está en a (sin dejar de estar en b)". Porque lo haces en este caso? es la implementación básica de una pila, cada nodo contiene el nodo anterior y tú siempre guardas el último nodo.  Pero lo más fácil es busques un video en youtube ahí podrás ver gráficamente cómo funciona el asunto de las colas y pilas

Comment: Ahh vale, muchas gracias colega. Recién empiezo en la programación y aún no tengo claro esos conceptos.